# CJK regex pattern

Tags: regex, xml, schema

What can be the regex pattern for accepting all characters and numbers(0-9) from CJK character set (Chinese, Japanese & Korean) except special characters?

Comment: Depends on what language you're using. Some regex flavours support Unicode character classes such as `\pL` (any letter in any script). Hard to say for your use-case without having specified a language.

Answer (score 0):

This info gleaned from the [UCD Interface](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn8/UCDusage.htm)
This is the latest Unicode 10 info.
Output is 88,964 characters.

From the Interface:

Used the Properties search for *CJK*, they were added to the Custom Rx page along with
the filter that they must be letters or numbers and have an assigned slot.

The regex's

```
 # CJK et all
 [\p{Block=CJK_Compatibility}\p{Block=CJK_Compatibility_Forms}\p{Block=CJK_Compatibility_Ideographs}\p{Block=CJK_Compatibility_Ideographs_Supplement}\p{Block=CJK_Radicals_Supplement}\p{Block=CJK_Strokes}\p{Block=CJK_Symbols_And_Punctuation}\p{Block=CJK_Unified_Ideographs}\p{Block=CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_A}\p{Block=CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_B}\p{Block=CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_C}\p{Block=CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_D}\p{Block=CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_E}\p{Block=CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_F}\p{Block=Enclosed_CJK_Letters_And_Months}] 
 # Must be letters or numbers
 (?<= [\p{L}\p{N}] )
 # Leave out the unassigned slots
 (?<! \p{General_Category=Unassigned} )
```

Output converted to UTF-8/32

```
 (?:
      [\x{3005}-\x{3007}\x{3021}-\x{3029}\x{3031}-\x{3035}\x{3038}-\x{303C}\x{3220}-\x{3229}\x{3248}-\x{324F}\x{3251}-\x{325F}\x{3280}-\x{3289}\x{32B1}-\x{32BF}\x{3400}-\x{4DB5}\x{4E00}-\x{9FEA}\x{F900}-\x{FA6D}\x{FA70}-\x{FAD9}\x{20000}-\x{2A6D6}\x{2A700}-\x{2B734}\x{2B740}-\x{2B81D}\x{2B820}-\x{2CEA1}\x{2CEB0}-\x{2EBE0}\x{2F800}-\x{2FA1D}]
 )
```

Output converted to UTF-16

```
 (?:
      [\x{3005}-\x{3007}\x{3021}-\x{3029}\x{3031}-\x{3035}\x{3038}-\x{303C}\x{3220}-\x{3229}\x{3248}-\x{324F}\x{3251}-\x{325F}\x{3280}-\x{3289}\x{32B1}-\x{32BF}\x{3400}-\x{4DB5}\x{4E00}-\x{9FEA}\x{F900}-\x{FA6D}\x{FA70}-\x{FAD9}] 
   |  
      (?:
           [\x{D840}-\x{D868}] [\x{DC00}-\x{DFFF}] 
        |  \x{D869} [\x{DC00}-\x{DED6}\x{DF00}-\x{DFFF}] 
        |  [\x{D86A}-\x{D86C}] [\x{DC00}-\x{DFFF}] 
        |  \x{D86D} [\x{DC00}-\x{DF34}\x{DF40}-\x{DFFF}] 
        |  \x{D86E} [\x{DC00}-\x{DC1D}\x{DC20}-\x{DFFF}] 
        |  [\x{D86F}-\x{D872}] [\x{DC00}-\x{DFFF}] 
        |  \x{D873} [\x{DC00}-\x{DEA1}\x{DEB0}-\x{DFFF}] 
        |  [\x{D874}-\x{D879}] [\x{DC00}-\x{DFFF}] 
        |  \x{D87A} [\x{DC00}-\x{DFE0}] 
        |  \x{D87E} [\x{DC00}-\x{DE1D}]
      )
 )
```